# How to catch a javascript error (cannot read property 0 of undefiend )

Tags: javascript, aura

Do you have any idea how can to catch javascript error **(cannot read property 0 of undefiend )**. I observed that javascript returns an error if you parse or you are trying to get the value of not existing property of an object like in the picture and you are writing this code to retrieve the value of object property. **object[0][0].Event_Product__r.Maximum_Simultaneous_Checkin__c** . The javascript will return an error of (cannot read property 0 of undefiend ) .

OBJECT WITH PROPERTIES

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should check the parent array dimension for existence before trying to use the child dimension, `if(typeof(data[i])!=="undefined")` and prevent the loop from going out of the array bounds `data[i].length` will give the number of elements in it.

In your case check `if(typeof(object[0][0])!=="undefined")` and do your stuff or else you can use `try catch` block to catch the JavaScript error like any other language.

```
try{
    undefinedfunction()
    alert('I guess you do exist')
}
catch(e){
    alert('An error has occurred: '+e.message)
}
finally{
    alert('I am alerted regardless of the outcome above')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I have an Idea.

In your case, the error you have mentioned will come if the Object is undefined, not when you try to access an non existent property like "Maximum_Simultaneous_Checkin__c".

I believe you should check the size of the array and also whether a property exists or not via hasOwnProperty.

Please not that hasOwnProperty will return false for inherited properties.

[MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

> **Example**
>
> Check if Object is undefined and length is more than zero. the following code will check whether the object is undefined or not.

```
    if(object && object.length>0 && object[0] && object[0].length>0) {
         //do something 
         //Check if a property exists using has hasOwnProperty (in case it is object).
    }
```

or you can simply wrap your code in try catch.